# MaxScript : How to compress a file content with zip or maxzip

Tags: maxscript

I've wrote an exporter for 3Dsmax using MaxScript.

File into which content is exported to is in a binary format, not a text file.

I would like to, at the end of the export, compress binary content using zip (for example, some equivalent to [php's gzencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php)).

Is there a way that MaxScript can natively do this?

Or if not, is there a way maxscript can  call an .exe or a .bat file with parameters, in which case I could then have an external tool to do compression?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are the `maz`/`unmaz` commands (for **ma**x **z**ip):

```
maz <filename>archiveFile <filename or filename array>input
```

Comment: Unfortunately, though it does create archive with a file inside, is not a solution I can use. 

What `maz` does is this: https://ibb.co/zNP3CRJ
It creates an archive witha folder structure inside, that contains a file.

What I would need is this: https://ibb.co/kgwvFtT
Content of original file (bytes of the original file) to be zip (gz) encoded and saved as a binary file.

So not so much to create an archive with one or more files, rather to run through exported file bytes, compress them, and save back into either same file or a new one.

Comment: P.S. Example: [php's gzencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php) does that, so I'm looking for an equivalent in `maxscript`.


P.P.S. I've shared in previous comment 2 images, they show binary content of what `maz` outputs, compared to what `php gzencode` outputs.

Comment: You can use the gzip python module (in maxscript that would be `gzip = python.import "gzip"`) and its methods.